# PHP MySQL Multiple rows from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I want to send notifications to multiple users on my site. Their ID's are in an array ($userinput). $userinput holds member ID's seperated by a comma at the start of each value (like "7,1,2,3").

I want to run a query like this:

```
$sqlnot = "INSERT INTO lb_notif (to_id, time_sent, from_id, subject, message) VALUES ('$user_id_here', now(), '$logOptions_id', '$title', 'You have been invited to this group chat: <a href=profilechat.php?id=$logOptions_id&chat=$act_item_id>Click here to enter</a>.') ";
```

How would I be able to send this to all of these members?

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop the array and dynamically build the query:

```
$sqlnot = "INSERT INTO lb_notif (to_id, time_sent, from_id, subject, message) VALUES";
$parts = array();
foreach($userinput as $user) {
    $parts[] = "('$user', now(), '$logOptions_id', '$title', 'You have been invited to this group chat: <a href=profilechat.php?id=$logOptions_id&chat=$act_item_id>Click here to enter</a>.') ";
}
$sqlnot .= implode(',', $parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $id_string = "7,1,2,3";     
    $user_ids = explode(",", $id_string);

    foreach($user_ids as $user_id_here){
         $sqlnot = "INSERT INTO lb_notif (to_id, time_sent, from_id, subject, message) VALUES ('$user_id_here', now(), '$logOptions_id', '$title', 'You have been invited to this group chat: <a href=profilechat.php?id=$logOptions_id&chat=$act_item_id>Click here to enter</a>.') ";
    // execute your query here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert multiple time then foreach is a charm option as:

```
$ids = explode(",", $userinput);

foreach($ids as $user_id){
     $sqlnot = "INSERT INTO lb_notif (to_id, time_sent, from_id, subject, message) VALUES ('$user_id_here', now(), '$logOptions_id', '$title', 'You have been invited to this group chat: <a href=profilechat.php?id=$logOptions_id&chat=$act_item_id>Click here to enter</a>.') ";

}
```